# Evaluation Error while using the Hiera hash in puppet

Tags: arrays, puppet, hiera

I have the following values in my hiera yaml file:

```
test::config_php::php_modules :
  -'soap'
  -'mcrypt'
  -'pdo'
  -'mbstring'
  -'php-process'
  -'pecl-memcache'
  -'devel'
  -'php-gd'
  -'pear'
  -'mysql'
  -'xml'
```

and following is my test class:

```
class test::config_php (
$php_version,
$php_modules = hiera_hash('php_modules', {}),
$module_name,
){

class { 'php':
version => $php_version,
}

$php_modules.each |String $php_module| {
php::module { $php_module: }
}
}
```

While running my puppet manifests I get the following error:

```
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, create_resources(): second argument must be a hash   at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-f38a037289f9864906c44863800dbacf/ssh/manifests/init.pp:46:3 on node testdays-1a.vagrant.loc.vag
I am quite confused on what exactly am I doing wrong. My puppet version is 3.6.2 and I also have parser = future
```

I would really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your YAML was slightly off.

1. You don't really need quotes in YAML.
2. Your indentation was two instead of one.
3. Your first colon on the first time was spaced. This will throw a syntax error.

it should look more like this:

```
test::config_php::php_modules:
 - soap
 - mcrypt
 - pdo
 - mbstring
 - php-process
 - pecl-memcache
 - devel
 - php-gd
 - pear
 - mysql
 - xml
```

In the future try and look up YAML parsers like this: [link](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion and link, but I seem to be having the same problem even after adding the changing the Yaml.

Comment: It seems I didn't read Evaluation correctly. You're using create_resources function that you're not displaying in your code. Can you show us this piece?
Check that the second argument to the function is a hash.

You can find how to do this from here https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.1/data_sources.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my puppet version, somehow version 3.6 acts weird while creating resources, for instance it was failing on the following line,:

```
create_resources('::ssh::client::config::user', $fin_users_client_options)
```

The code snippet above is part of ssh module from puppet labs, which I assume is throughly tested and shouldn't be a reason for the an exception.

A further analysis led to the fact that the exception was thrown when the parameter parser = future was set in the config file

I cannot iterate using each without setting future as the parser, therefore I decided to change my source as follow:

I created a new class:

```
define test::install_modules {
php::module { $name: }
}
```

and then I changed the config config_php to:

```
class test::config_php (
$php_version,
$php_modules = [],
){

class { 'php':
version => $php_version,
}

install_modules { $php_modules: }
}
```

Everything seems to be much better now.